# Timezone issues when sending Calender entries using Java mail API

Tags: jakarta-mail, icalendar

We are using JavaMail API to send calendar entries. But the recipients of Outlook have time zone issues, as meetings show wrong timings. In general our approach is as follows:

First of all we have,
 SimpleDateFormat iCalendarDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss");

we then use iCalendarDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(receiverTimeZone));

Finally, we use Calendar.getInstance() for start and end to manipulate Calendar fields, 
and hence we have  Date startDate = startTime.getTime();
            Date endDate = endTime.getTime();

When we are about to send request as per icalendar specification we have   ,
"DTSTAMP:" + iCalendarDateFormat.format(startDate) + "\n" +
"DTSTART:" + iCalendarDateFormat.format(startDate)+ "\n"                  "DTEND:"  + iCalendarDateFormat.format(endDate)+ "\n"

Is this the correct approach?. Please comment.

Thanks

Comment: I'm just guessing, but...  It doesn't look like there's any timezone information in the date/time entries in the calendar appointment so perhaps it's interpreting those times as relative to the timezone of the sender, determined from the Date header in the message?

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

iCalendar format tracks the date-time separately from its intended time zone. You must juggle both parts appropriately.

Always use *java.time* classes. Never use legacy classes like `Calendar` & `SimpleDateFormat`.

## Details

Caveat: I have not used *iCalendar* data before. So I may be incorrect in my understanding.

Looking at [pages 31-33 of the RFC 5545 spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#page-31), it seems the authors of that spec assume you always want the date-time to be recorded separately from the time zone.

A moment, a point on the timeline, needs the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC. For example, "noon on the 23rd of January next year, 2021" is not a moment. We do not know if you mean noon in Tokyo Japan, noon in Toulouse France, or noon in Toledo Ohio US — all very different moments, several hours apart.

To provide the context of an offset, a date and time must be accompanied by a number of hours-minutes-seconds such as `08:00`. For an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds, use `+00:00`.

> 2021-01-23T12:00:00+00:00

As an abbreviation of an offset of zero, `+00:00`, the letter `Z` can be used, pronounced “Zulu”. For example:

> 2021-01-23T12:00:00Z

But, strangely, the iCalendar spec wants to track the date and the time-of-day separate from the time zone. So this:

> 2021-01-23T12:00:00

…and a time zone field elsewhere:

> America/New_York

And the iCalendar spec opts for the harder-to-read “basic” variation allowed by ISO 8601, which minimizes the use of delimiters. So this:

> 20210123T120000

For such a string, we must parse as a `LocalDateTime`. This class represents a date with a time-of-day but lacking any time zone or offset-from-UTC.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = dateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuuMMdd'T'HHmmss" ) ;
String input = "20210123T120000" ;  // “Basic” variation of ISO 8601 format.
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input , f ) ;
```

To determine a moment, we must apply a time zone. I assume iCalendar uses [proper time zone names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) (`Continent/Region` format) and not the 2-4 letter pseudo-zones such as `PST`, `CST`, `IST`, and so on.

```
String zoneName = receiverTimeZone ;  // Variable name taken from your code example, though you neglected to show its origins.
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( zoneName ) ;
```

Apply the zone to get a `ZonedDateTime`, a moment, a point on the timeline.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( z ) ;
```

Going the other direction, let's start with the current moment.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

And generate string values for iCalendar.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = dateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuuMMdd'T'HHmmss" ) ;
String iCal_DateTime = now.format( f ) ;
String iCal_ZoneName = now.getZone().toString() ;
```

---

Never use the terrible legacy date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java: `Calendar`, `GregorianCalendar`, `java.util.Date`, `SimpleDateFormat`, and so on. These were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without seeing the actual content of your iCalendar file, along with the expected start and end datetime with timezone information but you seem to be generating the DTSTART in floating time (datetime with local time). Although your code sample seems to imply that you have access to the recipient's timezone (receiverTimezone), this is a very fragile approach.

Instead, you should use either the datetime with UTC time or the datetime with local time and timezone (where the timezone does not have to be the receiver timezone).
If the event is not recurring, the most simple approach is to use datetime with UTC time.

See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.3.5 for the definition of each format.

Comment: Thanks to you all for your feedback. Also the intention is not to use recipient's timezone directly, but it was one  of the variation we were testing when things were not working. Anyway we will check using UTC.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, for which I struggle lot. So below are my findings:

Outlook works smoothly with `UTC` Timezone. If we set date & time with `UTC` Timezone then outlook automatically converts this `UTC` Time into user corresponding `Timezone`. We will have to use 'Instant' object for `DTSTART:, DTEND:` and for `DTSTAMP`(Optional but recommended) also.

Quick Test just use `"DTSTART:"+Instant.now()` in ical String.

And in Java 8 for getting `UTC` Time java time API provides `Instant.now()` through which you can get your system time in `UTC` format. Java 8 also provides method like

`a.` `Instant.ofEpochMilli()` - This returns Instant which can directly use in ical Sting.

`b.` `new Date().toInstant()` Which returns `UTC` Instant object.

There are few scenarios where input date and time sources are different:

1. If you are fetching Date and Time from database then in this case database is not storing Timezone its only saving Date & Time. So first convert the Date & Time in that Timezone in which it was saved in database, in my case I was storing Date & Time after converting in 'EST' Timezone and Date value was of `EST` but time zone was not there in DB. So while fetching Date & Time value from DB I have appended Timezone in the Date value and then further converted to `EPOC` time using below method

   ```
   public static long getEpocTimeWithTimezone(Date date) {

   SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
   DateTimeFormatter dateTimePattern = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
   LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(simpleDateFormat.format(date), dateTimePattern);

   long epochInMilliSeconds = dateTime.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/New_York")).toEpochSecond() * 1000;

   return epochInMilliSeconds;
    }
   ```

   Then Just Use as below code for ical String:

   ```
     Instant startDt = Instant.ofEpochMilli(getEpocTimeWithTimezone(//pass your date here 
     )).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES);
   ```

   Now set this Instant object(startDt) directly to `"DTSTART:"`:

   ```
    "DTSTART:"+startDt+"....then in same fashion "DTEND:" also.
   ```
2. In second scenario you have Date with Timezone (make sure after conversion you did not loses your actual Timezone, Like in 1st scenario after saving Date in DB we actually lost Timezone but it was showing Timezone `IST` that was dummy so be careful about this)

   So in this case just assume `myDateObject` is Date object. So just get the `Instant` (which 
   will be in UTC) object from `myDateObject` by using `toInstant()` of `Date` class.

   ```
     Instant startDt  = myDateObject.toInstant().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES);
   ```

   I am using `.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES);` because if we will not use this then 
   we might get some extra min or second in Meeting invite Time section.

   So the final String for outlook mail should be some like:

   ```
   .
   .
   .
   "BEGIN:VEVENT\n"+
   "DTSTART:"+startDt+"\n"+
   "DTEND:"+endDt+"\n"+
   .
   .
   .
   ```

   `VVI Note:` Since `Z` is representation of UTC time zone, So just adding `Z` in the last of Time will not be `UTC` zoned Time, You will have to convert the Date & Time then only accurate time will come on Outlook. For verifying your Time is in UTC format or not just save the .ics attached file (which you got in Email) in local and check Date & Time are coming as `DTSTART:2020-05-15T13:57:00Z` or not If not then you are not converting the Date correctly in `UTC`.

Comment: Your first code snippet could be shortened to a one-liner: `long millis = myJavaUtilDate.toInstant().toEpochMilli()`. No need to define any method at all. Furthermore, never use `LocalDateTime` when you are trying to track a specific moment.  That class cannot represent a moment.

Comment: No need for your second code snippet. Calling `java.util.Date::toInstant` gives you an `Instant` object directly.